# Getting error using the lightning Data Services

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-data-service

I am trying to understand how I can leverage Lightning Data Service instead of calling Apex Class to retrieve the record details and updating it. Here I am having a simple button which has to update the few fields on the Contact record.

Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader">
  <aura:attribute name="record" type="Contact" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Contact' }" />
  <aura:attribute name="complete" type="Boolean" default="false" />
  <force:recordData recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                    fields="['FirstName','LastName','Email','AccountId']"
                    targetFields="{!v.record}"
                    aura:id="recordData"
                    recordUpdated="{!c.recordLoaded}" />
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({ 
  recordLoaded: function(component, event, helper) {
    var contactRecord = component.get("v.record"),
      recordData = component.find("recordData");
    contactRecord.FirstName = "";
      contactRecord.LastName = contactRecord.Email ;
      contactRecord.AccountId = "001R000001Zfpl2IAB";
    if(!component.get("v.complete")) { // Avoid infinite loop
      component.set("v.complete", true);
      component.set("v.record", caseRecord);
      recordData.saveRecord($A.getCallback(function(result) {
        if(result.state === "SUCCESS" || result.state === "DRAFT") {
          $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
          $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
        } 
      }));
  }
  }})
```

When I click on the quick Action on the Contact record I am getting the below error

`Action failed: c:SpamContact$controller$recordLoaded [Cannot set property FirstName of #<Object> which has only a getter]`

Can anyone please help what I am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `force:recordData` uses the "`VIEW`" `mode`. This mode makes the object read-only, but allows it to return the data faster, as it does not have to copy the object out of the LDS (Lightning Data Service) cache. To enable editing, use the `"EDIT"` `mode`, which has to perform extra work to copy the record, but the copy returned is directly editable.

---

```
  <force:recordData recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                    mode="EDIT"
                    fields="['FirstName','LastName','Email','AccountId']"
                    targetFields="{!v.record}"
                    aura:id="recordData"
                    recordUpdated="{!c.recordLoaded}" />
```